# How can I mark multiple lines at once for debugging in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

For example I have a python function that goes from line 4 to 27. How do I quickly mark every line with red dot in visual studio code for debugging without having to mark each line individually? It is super slow and tedious having to mark them one by one.

Comment: out of curiosity, what's undesirable about just breaking the first line(s) and then using the "step over" function?

Comment: I did not know that such "step over" exists. How do you use step over?

Comment: how do you plan to go from breakpoint to breakpoint

Comment: it is always nice to first read the doc pages about the debugger you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *might* be a better alternative to get what you want. You can set a breakpoint at whichever lines of code are executed *first* that you want to break upon, and then instead of putting breakpoints on the lines of code that are executed after, just use the "step over" feature of the debugger. See also the [VS Code docs on Debugger Actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions):

> Step Over <kbd>F10</kbd>
> Execute the next method as a single command without inspecting or following its component steps.

I tried googling "`github vscode issues add breakpoint multiple consecutive lines`" to see if someone had already raised a feature request for exactly what you asked for, but didn't see anything that looked like a match in the top search results. If using "step over" doesn't solve your problem, you can [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for such a feature to be added. If you do, make sure to provide enough detail to understand what you are asking for and an example of what it would look like / how to use the feature you want.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.